# Using 'DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, initializer

When I add this code `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges());` in DbContext file, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have included the System.Data.Entity namespace.  What could I be missing?
**EDIT**
I tried with DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StudentDbContext>());`

Answer (score 0):

you mean `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` not `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`